# Nuxt.js Vuex module not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm having problems with Nuxt's Vuex using it in modules.

It turns out that the `state` is being declared and appears in Vuex, the actions are triggered, but the `mutation` changes the `state` instance, but do not commit the change and do not even trigger the event, as it does not appear in the Vuex devtools console, below Vuex module code.

Note: in both `console.log()` print the state, in the first, empty, as it was declared, and in the second, the changed state, but the change does not really reflect in Vuex.

```js
export const strict = false
export const state = () => ({
  address: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  setShopAddress(state, address) {
    console.log(state)
    state.address = address
    console.log(state)
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getAddress({
    commit
  }) {
    this.$axios
      .get('/general/address')
      .then((response) => {
        commit('setShopAddress', response.data)
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error(e))
  },
  setAddress(vuexContext, address) {
    vuexContext.commit('setShopAddress', address)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getShopAddress(state) {
    return state.address
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours and thanks to a group of Nuxt on Telegram I was able to find the solution, I just needed to put an async on nuxtServerInit and an await on the call to action.

Code below:

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('module/action')
},
```

I hope my answer helps more people